# Autoincrement version per Foreign Key SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a table of an entity called `Entity` like this:

```
Entity
---------------------------
id (uniqueidentifier)
name (varchar(32))
description (varchar(max))
```

And i want to add a `record book` or `log` table to store all the version of Entity, named `EntityLog`

```
EntityLog
-------------------------
version ???
entityId (uniqueidentifier) fk Entity
name (varchar(32))
description (varchar(max))
```

The version column of `EntityLog` is merely a sketch, it can be manipulated because it does not exists yet.

**How can I assign automatically the version based on the foreign key `EntityId` so that inserts automatically update the version from 1, to 2, and so on, per `EntityId` no per table?**

Avoiding race conditions whenever possible, the context includes a multithreaded app

*Edit*

Attempt to solve it:

1. Read max version `select max(version) from entityLog where entityId = myId`
2. Insert into `EntityLog` with that previously read number + 1 or simply 1 if its null

Between 1 and 2 there may be race conditions, therefore I was hoping to delegate to SQL Server a thread-safe way of inserting like this

Comment: How do you decide when version number is different? on each insert to EntityLog?

Comment: @AdinugrahaTawaqal yes, the first insert correspond to the first version (number 1) and so on

Comment: You can use normal identity column on EntityLog and when you want to show version number order by said column and use ROWNUMBER() function as version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you care about accuracy MAX(Col) + 1 is not a good approach. Maybe you just need a datetime column for when the EntityLog was added. Then you could create a computed column using ROW_NUMBER and partition it by entityID.

Comment: @AdinugrahaTawaqal I finally added a identity column and a stored procedure with rownumber() partitioned by entityId to achieve the versioning. Thanks for the tip, you may post as an answer and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal identity column on EntityLog and when you want to show version number order by said column and use [ROWNUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function as version.